# Visual Studio - Ошибка сегментации как находить, как править?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++

[Есть кроссплатформенный проект](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/?r=1109#svn/branches/v0.4/Boost.Extension.Tutorial%253Fstate%253Dclosed). Под ОС Windows приложение собирается и падает во время работы, под ОС Linux - падает [не у всех](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847769/boost-extension-reflection-how-to-fix-segmentation-fault-error-when-compiling-off/5849377#5849377) с ошибкой `Segmentation fault`. Как под ОС Windows найти и исправить ошибку с помощью Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найти ошибку можно с помощью отладчика или анализируя дамп.

1. Запустить приложение в отладочном варианте.
2. Дождаться падения и вызова зарегистрированного отладчика.
3. В отладчике определить место падения, а затем уже смотреть по модулю/коду, что не так.

Какой отладчик выбрать: или встроенный Visual-Studio, или WinDbg, смотря что привычнее. Еще иногда помогают ADPlus и DebugDiag.

Ссылки.

- [Отладка в Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sc65sadd.aspx)
- [Отладка машинного кода](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k70yt3e2.aspx)
- [Вопросы и ответы по отладке машинного кода](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b6f9w27a.aspx)